# Compare 2 strings issue

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've my bloc elif with a loop inside that compare 2 strings (letters) but even if i put the right letter it still run the loop.. i've been looking thru the forum, tried many things but it still run the loop i've no idea why.

```
elif wallet > 0: # if player still wants to play (if wallet is not empty)
            restartp = raw_input('Keep playing [y/n] ? ')

            while restartp != 'y' or restartp != 'n':
                    print '[!] Wrong answer !'
                    restartp = raw_input('Keep playing [y/n] ? ')

            if restartp == 'y':
                    restart = 1

            elif restartp == 'n':
                    restart = 0
                    keep = False
```

Comment: no i have seen this post, tried both methods didn't help. I have been trying few things but i always get the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`restartp != 'y' or restartp != 'n'` will always be True.

You can use instead:

```
restartp != 'y' and restartp != 'n'
```

or alternatively:

```
while restartp not in ('y', 'n'):
```